# take a char and print out from char to 'a' and reverse it should be recursive

Tags: python, recursion, char

this is what Ii wrote so far but it is not the correct output

```
def characters(char):
    numb=ord(char)
    while numb>ord('a'):
      print chr(numb),
        numb=numb-1

    return
```

**I want the this output**:

```
characters('h')
    g f e d c b a
```

Comment: @Nathon: no it's not ...... I'm studying for an exam ,,:(((

Comment: Do you understand what "recursive" means? If not, that's probably something you should *really* be reading up on.

Comment: lol well thx, I know that it should be if-statement ... but even though, I really don't know how to go on with the rest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you design a recursive function, the first thing you want to ask yourself is: how does the algorithm terminate? I.e., what's the base case? In your example, the algorithm should stop printing characters after the letter 'a' is printed, so that's your base case.

Next, you have to ask how to get to the base case from your starting case. That's pretty easy: you want to print the previous character until you reach the base case. (A character is essentially just an integer, so that means you want to subtract one from the character and print it as a string.)

Putting that all together, I got:

```
def print_reverse(ch):
    print ch,
    if ch > 'a':
        print_reverse(chr(ord(ch)-1))
    else:
        print   # New line

print_reverse('h')
```

(If you don't know what the Python functions `ord` and `chr` do, look them up in the interactive interpreter using `help(ord)` and `help(chr)`.)

Answer (score 3):

Your function should be designed to call itself if it has to be [recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29):

```
def recurse_chars_down(char):
    if char <= 'a':
        print char
    else:
        print char,
        recurse_chars_down(chr(ord(char) - 1))

>>> recurse_chars_down('h')
h g f e d c b a
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive :

```
def character(char):
    print(char)
    character(chr(ord(char)-1))
    return
```

Comment: ok... check the latest condition... just like Frederic does...

Answer (score 0):

```
def characters(char):
    if char == 'a':
        return ''
    next_char = chr(ord(char)-1)
    return next_char+' '+characters(next_char)
```

---

```
>>> characters('h')
'g f e d c b a '
```